# Problem with collapsiblepanelextender

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, collapsiblepanelextender

CollapsiblePanelExtender inside user control not remembering its client state

Hi i have a user control being loaded dynamically. Inside this user control i have a CollapsiblePanel when i have a button inside or outside the collapsable panel and create a post back it does not remember the CollapsablePanels State. I have copied the code exactly from toolkit into empty user control and same thing happens as previously. I also paste the same code onto a blank aspx page and it works as it should.

Has anyone run into this problem and if so if you could provide some help that would be great. As i have been on this problem for a while now

Answer (score 0):

After loaded the user control, do you set a unique id?

```
var control = LoadControl("my.ascx");
control.ID = "MyAscxID";

....
```

If not, your viewstate won't be restored.

Comment: I do follow your suggestion. But my problem not yet fixed.Exaclly when I do AsyncPostBackTrigger error below occur Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Please help me soon